# React Native element type is invalid in useEffect

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

The useEffect in the code below generates the following error on load:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of "Page".
```

Code:

```
import {Stack, useRouter} from "expo-router";
import {Card, Menu, Text} from "@ui-kitten/components";
import {AuthService} from "../services/AuthService";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function Page() {
const router = useRouter();

const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);
const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);
const [activeCompany, setActiveCompany] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    AuthService.getAuth().then(tempAuth => {
        setAuth(tempAuth);

        if (tempAuth !== null) {
            setCompanies(tempAuth.companies)

            AuthService.getActiveCompany().then(activeCompany => {
                    console.log(activeCompany, 'active company')
                    setActiveCompany(activeCompany);
                }
            )
        }
    })
}, [])

return (
    <>
        <Stack.Screen
            options={{
                title: activeCompany === null ? 'Choose company' : activeCompany.name,
                headerBackVisible: false
            }}/>
    </>
)
}
```

Logging the 'company' variable to the console confirms it's actually NOT null or undefined. I've also tried hardcoding the following:

```
setActiveCompany({id: 'test'});
```

It gives the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was caused by a missing import further down in the code, so be sure to go through your imports if you're experiencing this confusing error.